# Changing PrinterSettings.Copies Not Working

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I am using WPF .Net Framework 4.0

What I expect is 3 pages, but I am only getting 1

```
var doc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
document.PrintPage += Document_PrintPage;
document.Print();

private void Document_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) {
    e.PageSettings.PrinterSettings.Copies = 3;
    e.PageSettings.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.Copies = 3;
    ...
}
```

It works when I set `PrinterSettings.Copies` before `document.Print()`

```
document.PrinterSettings.Copies = 3;
```

But this way it prints all pages 3 times

But `e.HasMorePages` can be true and each page can have different copy count, so I have to set it inside `Document_PrintPage`

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is very much by design.  The MSDN docs could be a bit more explicit about it, and an exception wouldn't hurt, but this restriction is very much a side-effect of the printing architecture in Windows.  The printer driver needs to know this detail up front.  Your PrinterSettings are used at the *start* of the print job and cannot be changed while printing is in progress.  What you can do *while* printing is limited, but otherwise well represented by the QueryPageSettings event.  Which allows changes to the PageSettings only.

In a WPF app you'd more likely use the System.Printing namespace, the number of copies is set by the PrintTicket.CopyCount.  Exact same limitation, you can't change the ticket while printing.

The only other thing you can do is render the page repeatedly to get the desired number of copies.  I'll have to wing it, the snippet in the question is not detailed enough to determine how you set the HasMorePages property.  We'll need some variables:

```
    public bool IsPrintPreview { get; set; }   // True to avoid copies while previewing
    public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }     // Determines HasMorePages

    private int PageNumber;                    // Page number while printing
    private int PageCopyCount;                 // Copy counter
```

And I'll make up a method that determines how many copies should be rendered for each individual page:

```
    private int GetNumberOfCopies(int page) {
        if (page > NumberOfPages) return 0;
        if (IsPrintPreview) return 1;
        // TODO: modify this
        return 3;
    }
```

We need the BeginPrint event to initialize the counters:

```
    private void Document_BeginPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e) {
        PageNumber = 1;
        PageCopyCount = GetNumberOfCopies(PageNumber);
        if (PageCopyCount == 0) e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

And the logic in the PrintPage event to count the copies and pages:

```
    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) {
        // Draw output for page# PageNumber
        //...
        // Count copies and pages
        e.HasMorePages = true;
        if (--PageCopyCount == 0) {
            PageNumber += 1;
            PageCopyCount = GetNumberOfCopies(PageNumber);
            if (PageCopyCount == 0) e.HasMorePages = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good answer but does not solve the problem. I still have to do same calculations again for multiple copies. If a page's copy count is 10, I make calculations 10 times, this is what I want to avoid.

Comment: You are talking about code that nobody can see.  Of course you can't get decent advice for that.  If you need to store calculation results in a collection or class so you can use them 10 times while printing then so be it.